# Is this picture of Trump, Bloomberg, and Clinton playing golf real?

Tags: politics, donald-trump, bill-clinton, michael-bloomberg

[image: Picture of Guillini, Trump, Bloomberg and Clinton]

Picture reads *"it's  big club and you ain't in it"*, and has Rudy Giuliani, Donald Trump, Michael Bloomberg, and Clinton.

That's quite similar to this tweet of the same Image without the caption by [Glenn Greenwald](https://twitter.com/ggreenwald/status/1223374556376772609)

Comment: Where was this claim being made?

Comment: @Oddthinking is the question who shared it, or who claimed that the people inside it are the people mentioned? I got it from FB. However, I've been told previously that beyond "facebook" it wasn't necessary to specify where I get images. I've seen this one going around quite a bit though. Here is Glenn Greenwald sharing it too, https://twitter.com/ggreenwald/status/1223374556376772609?lang=en

Comment: We are looking for evidence that it is widely believed. If it is being shared on Facebook, it is nice to point to a public instance that has many likes or shares to demonstrate that. In this case, where it is a self-answered question about politicians, it triggers nervousness about people who have tried to use Skeptics.SE as a propaganda tool in the past.

Comment: FWIW it is not a secret that the Clintons and Trumps used to be friends. Trump even phoned them the night before he declared his candidacy. That's one of the reasons I used to think he was scamming everyone with his sudden Republicanness (and, to this day, have no clue what's happened there). So, while I'm not in any way saying that this is a bad or off-topic question, I'm not sure the "skeptic" basis is very strong! As such @Oddthinking, yes there should be evidence that this is widely believed, but I'm noting that the vast majority of people likely do believe it, because it is widely known.

Comment: Although, strangely, some of the comments on this page _do_ suggest that at least some people have forgotten...

Comment: @Oddthinking A Q answered so quickly/immediately as to trigger HNQ is certainly of the plug type. There is zero claim and zero reason to challenge the authenticity of the picture. I'd be more interested in art-history interpretations of the relationship of wearing shorts towards claimed political affiliation; much like Kreml astrology and baldness/beards…

Comment: ^ In the age of the internet "zero claim and zero reason to challenge the authenticity of the picture". Skeptical you are not.

Comment: Have to agree with @Oddthinking's nervousness about SE.Skeptics being used as a political tool.  It'd seem better if the question asked about memes based on the original image, which the OP had access to at the time of posting.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Self-answered questions can be very quick (though the same second is impressive).  They raise different issues from full immediate answers by others

Comment: @Henry wait until you find out that I used the specific functionality called, `Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style` which is a core part of the site and enabled on creation of the question, before anyone else can even see it!

Comment: My understanding is that Skeptics requires a notable claim and a challenge to that claim.  The notability of this claim was not demonstrated, but even more, there was no indicated challenge.  Normally, the OP can declare a challenge for themselves, but having a literally immediate self-answer of "oh, it's totally legit" kind of gives that one the lie.

Comment: The implicit claim is that the picture is fake. The skeptical assumption is that all pictures I find on social media are fake. The refutation comes in the form of a notable source. I've seen this picture many times. This is where I grabbed the one with the caption: https://www.facebook.com/OccupyHouston/posts/2868598636540678?comment_id=2868692809864594 but I had seen it floating around on Glenn Greenwald's twitter too (no caption). And there is another one just like it with a different font that's also going around. https://i.pinimg.com/originals/74/32/db/7432dbad8ba3bff03c05019dbe28a679.jpg

Answer (score 64, accepted):

"Yes, it's real. It seems to be taken from,

[image: Picture unmodified]

https://newrepublic.com/article/155733/trump-clinton-bloomberg-giuliani-golf-photo-vainglorious-eternals

"Famous men with big drivers attend a 2008 charity event at Trump National Golf Club in Briarcliff Manor, N.Y. (Sabo Robert/NY Daily News Archive/ Getty)"

Note the two men cropped from the original are "Yankees Manager Joe Torre and professional Yankees fan Billy Crystal"